# AB testing: Control was performing 0.5% better than experiment set before the initiation of experiment

Tags: bias, ab-test, hypothesis-testing

So we introduced a new feature in our app, that would aid conversion (hypothetically).
When i tried to measure this incremental change in conversion, i split my base set of customers into control(C) 30% and test(T) 70% sets via random sampling.
Though feature was live to all customers for more than 2 months, we started an experiment say from Aug 19th (t1) where showed the feature only to the customers in test and control was not shown this feature.

What i observed is, for more than 1 month time period before t1 conversion of C was say 29.5%. And that of T's was 29% (both are averaged conversion calculated over 1 month before exp start).

Now after Aug 19th (after t1) C's conversion was say 31% and T's conversion was say 31.2% (measured over 1-2 weeks after exp started).

Now, I want to calculate the improvement in conversion as follows:

Before t1:
Diff in conversion (test-control) = 29-29.5 = -0.5%

Afer t1:
Diff in conversion (test-control) = 31.2-31 = 0.2%

So change in conversion was 0.2-(-0.5) = **0.7%**

So test added to an improved 0.7% conversion

**Is this the right way to calculate when control set was already having a biased better performance than experiment set before start of experiment?** (Assume i will run this exp for few more weeks & also do significance test further, but assume it was significant)

Some more info: The hoped improvement was also in the range of 1% itself. Plus, # of times control doing better than test before experiment start(t1) was about 67% now its come down to about 40%. Hence i am inclined to strongly argue test is adding ~0.7% value.